# Using vue-cli, components throw "Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I installed `vue-cli` and made some components, and everything was working great until I had to update some object values with keys

```
obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3
};
```

The data is updating, but the view isn't updating and when I dig into [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) it says

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue

The solution would be to use `Vue.set()` but when try that (inside my component) I get the following result:

```
Vue.set(example1.items, indexOfItem, newValue);
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Comment: Show the code where you define and trying to change this object.

Comment: Make sure your component imports the Vue module at the top of the file or at the top of the script section:
`import Vue from 'vue';`

Comment: Great, that's work :)

Answer (score 6):

You probably forgot to import your Vue in the component you're in

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

This should solve

Answer (score 0):

You forget the most important thing to introduce vue. The simplest, we can directly in the html file in the script tag to introduce vue, such as:

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In projects that use vue, individuals do not recommend configuring webpack and vue-loader separately. You can directly use vue official scaffolding, vue-cli. Do not have to consider these configurations, automatically configured.

[vue-cli](https://vuejs.org/2015/12/28/vue-cli/)

If you just started learning Vue, here's an entry-level demo. Although it is only a small application, but it covers a lot of knowledge points (vue2.0 + vue-cli + vue-router + vuex + axios + mysql + express + pm2 + webpack), including front-end, back-end, database and other sites Some of the necessary elements, for me, learning great significance, would like to encourage each other!

[Vue Demo](https://github.com/alloyteamzy/vue2_blog/)